# World at War modded zombie maps connecting to online

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war, cod-world-at-war-zombies

I've recently bought World at War on Steam so that I could play custom modded zombie maps. Though I can play them in single player mode I can not connect to these maps in online multi player mode.

I was wondering what I could do to solve this problem. I've tried watching videos and I tried looking for other methods like attempting to make LAN parties but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I played this with a friend a few years back. I believe the way we did it was by inviting to a lobby from the friends list in-game. If that does not work, you may have to port-forward your router in order to get your friend to join.